# Where can I find the form API reference?

Tags: 8, community-official-site

[Form API Reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x) gives information about which properties to use for a form array, for Drupal 7.

Where can I see what properties I can use in `buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)`, such as #type, #title, #required, and other possible properties?

Actually I'm using the Drupal 7 information in Drupal 8, and it works, but there should/must be an updated page, I guess.

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements/8.6.x

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements/

Comment: @Kevin, I don't see the where in that page says the field can have entries like "#title", "#type" or "#required" etc. Where can I have this information? I've edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: It's really hard to find this information because it's not presented in the same manner. Essentially all elements implement [ElementInterface::getInfo()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21ElementInterface.php/function/ElementInterface%3A%3AgetInfo/8.6.x), and this is where that information is for each element. The api project on drupal.org really should implement a way to aggregate things like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many of the form element properties are listed in the documentation for the [`FormElement`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21FormElement.php/class/FormElement/8.7.x) class. The properties described there are:

- `#after_build`
- `#ajax`
- `#array_parents`
- `#default_value`
- `#description`
- `#disabled`
- `#element_validate`
- `#field_prefix`
- `#field_suffix`
- `#input`
- `#parents`
- `#process`
- `#processed`
- `#required`
- `#states`
- `#title`
- `#title_display`
- `#tree`
- `#value_callback`

[Form and render elements](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements/8.7.x) shows a list of the form and render elements implemented by Drupal core, with a link to the class implementing them.

> [image: screenshot]

It contains also the following sentences. (Emphasis is mine.)

> Each form and render element type corresponds to an element plugin class; each of them either extends [`\Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderElement`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21RenderElement.php/class/RenderElement/8.7.x) (render elements) or [`\Drupal\Core\Render\Element\FormElement`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21FormElement.php/class/FormElement/8.7.x) (form elements). Usage and **properties are documented on the individual classes**, and **the two base classes list common properties shared by all render elements and the form element subset**, respectively.

There isn't a single page describing all the form element properties, but there is a page for each plugin class that implements a form element.

Comment: I've updated Drupal documentation here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/form-render-elements. Thank you.